# Can a user able to see the extra achievements as well when the app goes live on the Google Play store?

Tags: android, google-play-games, publishing, android-gps, achievements

I have created some achievements for my app and published them on GPGS, but now I don't want them and created some more achievements and drafted the previously created achievements.

So, the current status for old achievements (example 6 achievements) is 'Changes available to testers'
and for the newly created (example 5 achievements)'Available to everyone'.

I have configured only 5 newly created (published on GPGS) achievements in the game.
All the 11 achievements are visible to Tester.

My question is, does the other achievements which are in the 'Changes available to testers' state is visible to users in the achievement section when my app goes live on the Google Play Store? or the user can only see the achievement which is in publish state and configured in the game?